# array out of bound exception:0

Tags: java, arrays, processing, speech-recognition

i have a code for controlling led on-off through voice. In the following processing 1.2 code, an array out of bound exception error is occurring please help me to get ride of this
error is in initialize function 2 line...

```
String words;  
String s;  
String str1= "on";    
String str2= "off";

void setup ()  {  
   initialize () ;  
 } 

void draw () {  
listen () ;  
}  

void respond (String input) {   

  if(input.length()>0) {    
      //user speaks any commands   
      voce.SpeechInterface.setRecognizerEnabled(false) ;    //stop    
     //Listening, decode and send command to robot    
      String [ ] words = split (input," ");     
      tts.speak(input) ;    //Play the spoken words  

      if(words[0].equals(str1)==true) {    
          robot.write ("A") ;    
      }    

      if(words[0].equals(str2)==true) {     
         robot.write ("B") ;    
      }   

      voce.SpeechInterface.setRecognizerEnabled(true);     
   }    
 }    

 /*void mousePressed () {    

 }    
 */    
 //Speech Function:      
 //import the libraries    
 import guru.ttslib.*;    
 import processing.serial.*;     

 //give our instances names     
 Serial robot;     
 TTS tts;    
 public void initialize() {    

  voce.SpeechInterface.init("libraries/voce-0.9.1/lib",true,true,"libraries/voce-                                                                                         0.9.1/lib/gram","digits");          
 println(Serial.list());     
 robot = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0],9600) ;     //start serial port and also tts   
 tts = new TTS() ;    
 //the following settings control the voice sound      
 tts.setPitch ( 90 ) ;     
 tts.setPitchRange ( 90 ) ;     
 }    

void listen () {     

  if(voce.SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize()>0 ) {         
     //if voce recognizes anything being said         
     s = voce.SpeechInterface.popRecognizedString();        
     //assign the string that computer heard to the variable s         
     println("you said: " + s) ;         
     //print what was heard to the debug window.        
     respond (s);         
   }          
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? How many indexes does the array on that line have? What index are you trying to access?

Comment: your input may not contain spaces. So while splitting it, the array "word" will have no element.And getting the element at word[0] may throgh out of bound exception.

Comment: @HansPassant Why did you remove the [processing] tag?

Comment: @The - Cobol is a language that is good at processing.  It is a meaningless meta tag.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, processing is a language. And it's the language being used here.

Comment: Sigh, worst name for a language.  So just change the tags.

Comment: can you please post the error message

Comment: An excellent opportunity to learn how to debug!!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I think your `split` command is returning no results. When you try access item #1 (position 0) of the `words` array, that throws an error.

Better to check that there are items in the array first:

```
String [] words = split(input," "); 
if(words.length > 0 && words[0].equals(str1) == true) {    
  robot.write ("A") ;    
}
```